# LIMIT для UNION

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Склеиваю 2 запроса UNION`ом, только вот беда, мне надо что бы результат возвращал 20 записей, но он возвращает 40

Если поставить в каждом запросе LIMIT 10 то вроде работает, но если в одной таблице будет всего 3 записи, а в другой 100, то результатом будет 13 запимей, а такого мне не надо

```
(
  SELECT * FROM `table1`
  ORDER BY `time` ASC LIMIT 20
)UNION ALL(
  SELECT * FROM `table2`
  ORDER BY `time` ASC LIMIT 20
)
ORDER BY `time` ASC
```

Comment: нужно UNION ALL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Сделайте агрегирующий запрос и в нем ограничивайте количество строк:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM `table1`
UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `table2`
)
ORDER BY `time` ASC
LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 2):

Последний `ORDER BY` и `LIMIT` действуют на весь `UNION`, поэтому подзапрос не нужен:

```
SELECT * FROM `table1`
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `table2`
ORDER BY `time` ASC
LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 1):

Напишите в последнем ORDER BY

```
ORDER BY `time` ASC LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Для полной картины дополню цитатой из документации:  

> To use an ORDER BY or LIMIT clause to sort or limit the entire UNION result, parenthesize the individual SELECT statements and place the ORDER BY or LIMIT after the last one. The following example uses both clauses:  


    (SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1)
    UNION
    (SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2)
ORDER BY a LIMIT 10;