# Выборка 10 последних записей из нескольких таблиц одним запросом

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть несколько таблиц. В каждой есть столбец `create_date`.
Необходимо вывести 10 последних записей из этих двух таблиц, отсортированных по `create_date`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли такая возможность, или необходимо делать несколько запросов к каждой таблице?

Comment: смотря что за столбцы нужно выбирать в каждой таблице.... если одноименные, то можно (но естью нюанс), если разноименные - то смысла в едином запросе нет

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, необходимо получить одноименные столбцы, конкретнее `id` и `name`

Comment: Тогда как раз подходим к нюансу: на выходе вам важно знать какие данные из какой таблиц или главное чтоб вывод был? и как оно должно быть отсортированные по дате одной таблице потом по дате другой? или всё вместе отсортированные

Comment: А что значит выбрать из двух таблиц. какие отношения данных в этих таблицах. т.е. строка из одной таблицы объединяется со строкой из другой (JOIN) или друг под другом (UNION) ?

Comment: какая структура у таблиц?

Comment: Не вот так случайно http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/244779/limit-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-union

Comment: @Mike ну вот, я специально по шагам выуживаю информацию. Всё испортил )))

Comment: @Mike, спасибо за ссылку. В итоге пришел к такому запросу `SELECT id,create_date FROM
(SELECT id,create_date FROM manuals
UNION ALL
SELECT id,create_date FROM comments) as t
ORDER BY create_date DESC
LIMIT 10`, все бы хорошо, но в результирующем наборе мне необходимо понять, из какой таблицы какой результат.

Comment: @ultimatum, таблицы две одинаковые. Содержат поля `id`, `name`, `create_date`.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, необходимо знать из какой таблицы результат, сортировка по дате общая.

Comment: Добавьте в выборку из таблиц признак третьим полем `SELECT id,create_date, 1 as X ...`

Comment: @Mike, получилось! Всем огромное спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо использовать агрегирующий запрос.

```
SELECT id,create_date,tablename FROM
(SELECT id,create_date, 'manuals' as tablename FROM manuals
UNION ALL
SELECT id,create_date, 'comments' as tablename FROM comments) as t 
ORDER BY create_date DESC
LIMIT 10
```